# CSS Opacity is not working in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, filter, opacity

I've look at the other questions about this, but can't find a solution.

I've tried this:

```
.picpic:hover{
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

the html is something like this

```
<a href="xx"><img class="picpic" src="zz.png"></a>
```

Can i get some help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that your IE-specific opacity line -`filter: alpha(opacity=50);` is being overidden by the general `opacity: 0.5;` line which works in the other browsers/versions of IE.

Try this specifically for IE7:

```
 <!--[if IE 7]>
    .opaque2 {  // for IE5-7
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }
 <![endif]-->
```

Make sure to use conditional comments if it's working fine for all other browsers/versions.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain why your code would work when the OP's does not?

Comment: Because he is overriding the IE7 opacity with normal opacity, if he takes the bottom opacity out or uses conditional comments specifically guaranteed it'll work in IE7.

Comment: @user1394965, I know.  I am merely suggesting that you _improve_ your answer by editing and appending it with such information.

Comment: @Sparky672 OK sorry about that, I'll improve it now.